# Python deep sort

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have the following object:

```
{
  a: {size: 4},
  b: {size: 8},
  c: {size: 2},
  d: {size: 3},
  e: {size: 9},
  f: {size: 23}
}
```

I need to sort this based on `size` in Python 2. I can find a lot of resource on shallow sorting, but I am not sure how to access the `size` value. I struggled with `sorted` and a `lamba` function, but it isn't working out. How do I go about this?

I last attempted this:

```
domains = sorted(items, key=lambda item: item['size'])
```

However got the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

#### Edit

I used @smarx's example to fix. As I needed to rebuild the full object and not just the keys, I ended up using:

```
for name in sorted(items, key=lambda k: items[k]['size'], reverse=True):
```

Comment: You say you "struggled" and it "isn't working". Provide your code. What did you try, what did you expect, what didn't work and how? Provide a full [MCVE]. Note: It might help if you spelled `lambda` correctly (assuming you made same typo in code).

Comment: Presumably you wish to sort based on `size` ... but you don't explicitly say that ... be more explicit as to your problem

Comment: Correct on both counts, ShadowRanger and donkopotamus

Comment: You were very close ... hint your lambda is being given a tuple of key and value ...

Comment: @donkopotamus: No it isn't; looks like they're passing the `dict`, not the `dict`'s items. The error is what you'd see if you tried to index the key (`str`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger indeed!

Comment: What output do you expect? Are you looking for a sorted list of keys, or do you want the values too? Or do you want your code to construct an `OrderedDict` so that you can still do dictionary lookups on the data?

Comment: @Blckknght updated my question to answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
d = {
    "a": {"size": 4},
    "b": {"size": 8},
    "c": {"size": 2},
    "d": {"size": 3},
    "e": {"size": 9},
    "f": {"size": 23}
}

print(sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k]["size"]))

# output:
# ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'f']
```

I converted the "object" to Python syntax. (I assume what I have above is what you meant?)

`sorted` takes a keyword argument `key`, which is a function that returns the thing to sort by. So I sorted using a `key` function that looks up the size for each key.

I hope that makes sense.

**UPDATE**

A couple other things you might want to try, depending on what output you're trying to get:

```
print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]["size"]))
print(sorted(d.values(), key=lambda value: value["size"]))
```

If none of these help, please tell us what output you actually want (keys, values, both, something else?).

Comment: Side-note: Calling `.keys()` is superfluous on Py3, and actively wasteful on Py2 (where it has to make extra temporary `list`s). `dict`s are already iterables of their keys, so omit the extraneous call.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks! Edited.

Comment: This was it, thanks so much. @ShadowRanger I'm at that entry point in Python where every question is very stupid because you simply don't even know enough jargon to ask the right question. At least I know my questions are stupid. Hope you'll forgive me :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use sorted on `dict.items()`, and set the sorting `key` to the item's value (index 1)'s `size` key.

```
dct = {
    "a": {"size": 4},
    "b": {"size": 8},
    "c": {"size": 2},
    "d": {"size": 3},
    "e": {"size": 9},
    "f": {"size": 23}
} 
print(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda d: d[1]["size"]))
```

Depends on what kind of output you want, this one returns:

```
[('c', {'size': 2}), ('d', {'size': 3}), ('a', {'size': 4}), 
 ('b', {'size': 8}), ('e', {'size': 9}), ('f', {'size': 23})]
```